# Disable spring boot all together when running maven test

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have some unit test classes in my project that I want to test with `mvn test`. But whenever I run the command an instance of spring boot starts and opens database connections.

I´m running these tests in a server that doesn´t have access to a database, and none of my tests uses one. I just one to execute the tests as the IDE does.

Comment: So you have defined in your test to run it that way. You should change your tests... apart from that they sound like integration tests and should be named like `*IT.java` instead of `*Test.java` ...that would solve the problem... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise my tests are not integration tests, they only have this annotation @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class), and yes they are called *test.java

Comment: There are many solutions: you could disable all test when build run on maven, refectoring your tests for swiching as you need, run tests mocking your database or point only tests for a specific configuration with a database on memory.

Comment: So interesting when you said `I just one to execute the tests as the IDE does`. IDE runs tests different to `mvn test`?

Comment: So if you execute a test which connects to a database it is an integration tests...

Comment: You have only test with `@ExtendWith(...)` ? None of them with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: @DilermandoLima yes, IDE executes tests without loading spring boot and without any autoconfiguration

Comment: @khmarbaise any of my tests use the database, they use mocks. I had an empty class with SpringBootTest, deleting it did the job, thanks

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` startups up the whole spring context which includes connections etc... that's usually not the correct way...

Answer (score 1):

I think one of them could help you

**1 - Disable all tests**

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

**2 - Prepare your test for switching**

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnabledIf(expression = "${tests.spring.enabled:true}")
```

if you pass `-Dtests.spring.enabled=` false or true will disable test

**3 - Point your test to other configuration**

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active:test}.properties")
```

this way you could connect your application into a local database

**4 - Change your tests**

Use mocks to turn your integration tests into a unit tests or component tests with no connections

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Disabled("TODO: Fix root cause")`

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Disabled.html

> public @interface Disabled
> @Disabled is used to signal that the annotated test class or test method is currently disabled and should not be executed.
> @Disabled may optionally be declared with a reason to document why the > annotated test class or test method is disabled.

> When applied at the class level, all test methods within that class are automatically disabled as well.

> When applied at the method level, the presence of this annotation does not prevent the test class from being instantiated. Rather, it prevents the execution of the test method and method-level lifecycle callbacks such as @BeforeEach methods, @AfterEach methods, and corresponding extension APIs.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I had was an empty class with `@SpringBootTest` annotation. After deleting it the tests works without spring interfering.